# powershell - how to check existence of one file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have folders with different count of files. How to check if there are some files and how many?
I use this, but when there is only one file, it gives me nothing. Thank you.

```
$number_of_files = Get-Childitem c:\folder -name -force
$number_of_files.Count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\folder -name -force | where {$_.GetType() -match "fileInfo"} | measure-object).count
```

Answer (score 5):

Change it like this:

```
$number_of_files = @(Get-Childitem c:\folder -name -force)
$number_of_files.Count
```

This force `$number_of_files` to be always an Array and have the count property rigth set
also for value of 1

Comment: This solution counts not only files, but also folders.

Comment: @MarekDzikiewicz I didn't notice that requirement in his Q. But you are right of course

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Marek works, but it perhaps not the most efficient. Rather than doing a .GetType() and doing a regex match, why not just filter based on a property in folder and not in file object. IE:

(Get-ChildItem c:\folder -name -force | where {! $_.PSIsContainer} | measure-object).count.

Answer (score 1):

I use `measure` for this:

```
$f = Get-Childitem c:\folder -name -force
($f | measure).Count
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this would also measure any folders in the c:\folder folder.

Comment: I didn't notice that requirement in his Q. But you are right of course.